# Range of the function $g_{\epsilon}(x)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I was thinking about the range of the function $g_{\epsilon}(x) = x e^{-k_{\epsilon}x^2}$.

where $x \in \Bbb{R}$ and $k_{\epsilon}$ is defined as $\forall \epsilon > 0,k_{\epsilon} = \frac{1}{2e\epsilon^2}$

How the range of the function $g_{\epsilon}(x)$ is $[-\epsilon,\epsilon]$?

Like if $x \rightarrow -\infty$, $g_{\epsilon}(x)  \rightarrow -\infty$?

How to find the range of the function$g_{\epsilon}(x)?$

Comment: As $x$ tends to negative (positive) infinity $g_\epsilon (x) $ tends to zero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}g_\varepsilon(x)=0
$$
and the same at $-\infty$, because the function is odd.

Moreover
$$
g_\varepsilon'(x)=(1-2k_\varepsilon x^2)e^{-k_\varepsilon x^2}
$$
so the function has a maximum at $x=1/\sqrt{2k_\varepsilon}$, with
$$
g_\varepsilon(1/\sqrt{2k_\varepsilon}\,)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k_\varepsilon}}e^{-1/2}=
e^{1/2}\varepsilon e^{-1/2}=\varepsilon
$$
Since the function is odd, the range is indeed $[-\varepsilon,\varepsilon]$.

It's perhaps simpler to consider $f(x)=xe^{-x^2}$; then, with the same argument as before, we see that it has a maximum at $1/\sqrt{2}$, where
$$
f(1/\sqrt{2})=\frac{e^{-1/2}}{\sqrt{2}}
$$
Clearly,
$$
g_\varepsilon(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{k_\varepsilon}}\,f(x\sqrt{k_\varepsilon}\,)
$$
so the maximum value is
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{k_\varepsilon}}\frac{e^{-1/2}}{\sqrt{2}}=\varepsilon
$$

Answer (score 1):

If $|x| \to \infty$, check that $g_\epsilon (x) \to 0$.

Now, let's check for minimal point and maximum point.

$$g_\epsilon(x) = x \exp(-k_\epsilon x^2)$$

$$g'_\epsilon(x)= \exp(-k_\epsilon x^2)-2k_\epsilon x^2(-k_\epsilon x^2) = 0$$

Hence the stationary point satisfies

$$1-2k_\epsilon x^2 = 0$$

$$x = \pm  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2k_\epsilon}}$$